# Use right context

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

Need to paste context in my constructor in `SwipeToDeleteCallback`, which is located in the fragment:

```
private val swipeHandler = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback() {

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        presenter.removeListItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }
}
```

Tried to insert `requireContext()` but catch KotlinNullPointerException.

Maybe I can somehow use the context here `viewHolder.context`?

Here is some code `SwipeToDeleteCallback`:

```
abstract class SwipeToDeleteCallback(context: Context) :
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

    private val deleteIcon = context.getDrawableCompat(R.drawable.ic_log_out)
```

Also i called my fragment from `MainActivity`:

```
override fun onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume()
    replaceFragment(TargetsFragment())
}

override fun showListOfTarget() {
    replaceFragment(TargetsFragment())
}
```

Here is full code of my fragment:

```
class TargetsFragment : Fragment(), ListItemClickListener, SelectTargetViewContract, BaseDataSetContract {

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private val presenter = TargetsPresenter(this)
    private var adapter = TargetsAdapter(clickListener = this)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_target_list, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        presenter.setInitialData()
        setupViews()
        updateListData()
    }

    override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
        presenter.onListItemClick((adapter.getItem(itemIndex) as Target).guid)
    }

    override fun showTarget(guid: String) {
        activity?.addFragment(TargetEditFragment.newInstance(guid))
    }

    override fun dataSetChanged() {
        updateListData()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun updateViewContent() {
        adapter.data = presenter.targetList
        recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView?.setVisible(presenter.shouldShowContent())
        emptyView?.setVisible(presenter.shouldShowEmptyView())
    }

    private fun updateListData() {
        if (presenter.firebaseUser == null) {
            Log.d("some", "loadLogInView")
        } else {
            presenter.getTargetsFromDb()
        }
    }

    private val swipeHandler = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback() {

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            presenter.removeListItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    private fun setupViews() {
        recyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code for `SwipeToDeleteCallback`?

Comment: Could you please provide more context. Where do you make a call. In Activity or Fragment, in which method?

Comment: Assuming you're in a `Fragment`, if `SwipeToDeleteCallback` has to have a `Context` in its constructor, then you cannot instantiate until at least `onAttach()`.

Comment: Wrap this constructor with a lazy delegate.

Comment: try `viewHolder.itemView.context`

Comment: @atarasenko here I think how to push it)

Comment: @MikeM. can u also check please my fragment? maybe you'll get the idea of how to insert the `context` in my `SwipeToDeleteCallback`

Comment: I updated my answer now, @MikeM. see if you agree with it please.

Comment: You cannot instantiate the `SwipeToDeleteCallback` in a field declaration. You only need it in the one method, so just move it into `setupViews()`.

Comment: @MikeM. it works with `requireContext()` but how i can use here simple `context`/`getContext`?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. If you move it into `setupViews()`, any of those will work.

Comment: @MikeM. i can t write smth like `SwipeToDeleteCallback(context)`, because found `Context?`

Comment: Oh, that. Well, I think you can use `context!!`, but what's wrong with `requireContext()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
yourViewHolder.itemView.context
```

to get the context of `yourViewHolder`

---

After clarification from OP:

---

Initially I thought you only wanted to get context from your ViewHolder, but here's an addition to my answer:

Try moving your code which requires context to `onAttach`, which you will have to override, from the documentation : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call getContext(). However, be careful to call getContext() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment isn't attached yet, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getContext() returns null.

The method you're looking for looks like this :

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

You will probably be safe to move all your code which requires context inside this method and assign it as you need to